# Is my coroutine script & spawning script killing my game together?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am curious if there is anything that stands out in these two script that could be causing me to drop frames and cause momentary lag. This first script is used  to instantiate Game Objects that have the 2nd script attached to it (2nd script spawns clones of itself). Before these game objects begin spawning, I drop frames and lag - and as I am building a game meant for the HTC Vive, I get a blue loading box in HMD.

thank you in advance.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class publicarray : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject[] ThingToKill;
public float startAfterThisManySeconds;
public float endafterThisManySeconds;

void Start()
{       
   for (int i = 0; i < ThingToKill.Length; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log(ThingToKill[i].name);
        ThingToKill[i].SetActive(false);
        StartCoroutine("turnOn");
        StartCoroutine("turnOff");
    }
}

IEnumerator turnOn()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(startAfterThisManySeconds);
    StartCoroutine("on");
    Debug.Log("on");
}

IEnumerator turnOff()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(endafterThisManySeconds + startAfterThisManySeconds);
    StartCoroutine("off");
    Debug.Log("off");
}

IEnumerator on()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ThingToKill.Length; i++)
    {
        ThingToKill[i].SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0f);
    }
}

IEnumerator off()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ThingToKill.Length; i++)
    {
        ThingToKill[i].SetActive(false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0f);
    }
}
}
```

Seconds script (Spawning) (*Edited* with correct script!)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TimedSpawn : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject spawnee;
public bool stopSpawning = false;
public float spawnTime;
public float spawnDelay;
public float height;
public float x1;
public float x2;
public float z1;
public float z2;
float timer = 0f;
public float amountoftimetospawn;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    InvokeRepeating("SpawnObject", spawnTime, spawnDelay);
}

public void SpawnObject() {
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    //Instantiate(spawnee, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    Instantiate(spawnee, (new Vector3((Random.Range(x1, x2)), height, 
   (Random.Range(z1, z2)))), spawnee.transform.rotation);
    if (timer > amountoftimetospawn) {
        CancelInvoke("SpawnObject");
      }
   }
}
```

Third Script that Destroys my Game objects:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnGameObjects : MonoBehaviour
{    
public float killtime;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "table")
    {            
        Destroy(gameObject, killtime);
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "floor")
        {              
            Destroy(gameObject, killtime);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Start is setting ThingToKill[i].SetActive(false) and calls turnOn() which calls on() and that sets ALL thingToKill[i].SetActive(true);. Afterwards you repeat with the next one which sets all of them active again. And why do you need a Coroutine in the first place that does nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they're leaching a lot of performance out of your game for pretty petty reasons.

You are iterating over all your GameObjects, multiple times, to activate and dis-activate them. You also aren't per-say 'Instantiating' them, at least not dynamically, it seems you have placed all your game objects in your scene and have placed them all manually in a Gameobject Array available in the Inspector. This isn't great, you are losing all extendability and it is very tedious.

Also, your spawn script, actually has nothing to do with any spawning whatsoever, all it does is actually destroy, which is pretty opposite to spawning, but anyways..

I think the road of having spawners is a good idea. A lot of what you posted should be scrapped IMO, for more optimized and flexible solutions, most of them can be implemented quite easily and you can actually browse a lot of these implementations in the [Official Unity Tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials).

I'd really advise going through some of them, or at least looking at all the types of chapters they offer, usually you will get very hands on and relatable experience.

IMO, you should have references to the all the GameObjects you wish to instantiate in game, categorize them (if applicable in your case) and use a spawning system, to correctly Instantiate them, when/where they are needed.

Also, it would really be better if you had concrete entities (ex: bullet, mob etc..)

These could for exemple implement let's say, an interface, called `IMortal` so that your entity has access to a `void DieAnim() { Destroy(gameObject, deathTime) }` . This would unburden your "spawning" script to not manage destruction, each entity would be in capacity to handle it's own death. Your spawner behaviour should, at best, only be the trigger.

Comment: Woah - Sorry and thank you for mentioning that, I had put the destroy script in the second chunk of code! I replaced the second part with the spawn script and put the 3rd script which deals with the destroying of the Game Objects.

Comment: The kill script has a weird second destroy option. You should check for floor outside the table check. First script is useless, if you ever need to know all objects to destroy, keep a list from your spawn script -> after each spawn it adds one entry.

Comment: @corbinyo Okay, so, first thing I see from your Spawner script is that you keep absolutely no reference of the Instance anywhere, maybe you don't need to, I don't really know how you plan on accessing them. But there is one big problem with your `OnCollisionEnter()`, you call destroy before an IF statement containing a nested Destroy of the exact same gameObject, for which no scenario exists where Destroy won't have been called once before the second one. What you should probably do if you want to limit check is have a `bool myState` or something else, and check valid colliders in the same IF